# Leaflet: loading JSON with Ajax not working

Tags: leaflet, geojson, json

I'm trying to remove an HTML `div` if an array of the JSON I'm loading matches the feature properties of my GeoJSON. Here is my code:

```
function geo_json_dc64d985f99647e7b35676bc82a64cc7_onEachFeature(feature, layer) {

    layer.on({
        mouseout: function(e) {
            geo_json_dc64d985f99647e7b35676bc82a64cc7.resetStyle(e.target);
        },
        mouseover: function(e) {
            e.target.setStyle(geo_json_dc64d985f99647e7b35676bc82a64cc7_highlighter(e.target.feature));
        },
        click: function(e) {
            map_ae26379126cd4ce79aea9d0f395ec09f.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());

            $.ajax({
                dataType: "json",
                url: "js/csvjson.json",
                success: function(dati) {
                    dati.forEach(function(arrayItem) {
                        if (arrayItem["Comune"] == e.target.feature.properties.NOME_COM) {
                            $('#welcome').remove();
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
        }
    });
};
```

You can see how it is working right now [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/yryUxJ0RCy6bFKeg5BgP?p=preview) (without the JSON, that can't be loaded).

My JSON looks like this:

```
"": 0,
"Comune": "BONDENO",
"PUNTEGGIOSCUOLA1516": 4.25,
"Value 1": 63,
"Value 2": 8,
"Value 3": 17,
"DANNO": 6,
"Somma valori": 88,
"numero_di_scuole": 4,
"CERTIFICATOAGIBILITAABITABILITA": "",
"DOCUMENTOVALUTAZIONERISCHIO": "",
"PIANOEMERGENZA": "",
"PUNTEGGIOSCUOLA1617": 5.5,
"VINCOLIPAESAGGIO": 1,
"EDIFICIOVETUSTO": 0,
"PROGETTAZIONEANTISISMICA": 1,
"VINCOLIIDROGEOLOGICI": 0,
"PUNTEGGIO_SCUOLE_PARITARIE_1516": "",
"PUNTEGGIO_SCUOLE_PARITARIE_1617": ""
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This looks more like a part of your JSON, and even this without required delimiters `{` and `}`. Any errors in the browser debugger console?

Comment: It is, my JSON is very long and it didn't format properly with the required delimiters! About the browser debugger console, it says:       Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/Users/annas/progetti_pycharm_vecchio_pc/openaccess/csvjson.json' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
jquery-1.12.4.min.js:4 GET file:///C:/Users/annas/progetti_pycharm_vecchio_pc/openaccess/csvjson.json net::ERR_FAILED

Comment: If you are running your page locally from file system and not from server, you will get CORS security error for files retrieved from local file system. Practical solution for testing purposes is to declare your JSON as JS variable `var myJSON = {...}` in file `my-json.js` and bring it in through script reference: `<script src="js/my-json.js"></script>`. Then of course you don't use AJAX but reference `myJSON` directly.

Comment: Hey, thank you, I'm trying but it doesn't seem to be working... no errors in the console now.

Comment: It's hard to say what's wrong without possibility to test it. Put part of you JSON (few items of the whole array) as variable in your Plunker code.

Comment: I have updated it [same link as before](https://plnkr.co/edit/740yVI4YNh38fZZjpqW0?p=preview) and here is the whole myjson.js file: [github](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dersuchendee/openaccessprova/master/myjson.js)

Comment: Your comparison logic is now false. You should retain the same logic as when reading JSON from file and iterate through elements: `myJSON.forEach`.

Comment: I see, thanks! I'm not great at this... now I put `myJSON.forEach(function(arrayItem) {
                                            if (arrayItem["Comune"] == e.target.feature.properties.NOME_COM) {` etc., still doesn't work

Comment: Please update your Plunker.

Comment: [it should be updated now!](https://plnkr.co/edit/740yVI4YNh38fZZjpqW0?p=preview)

Comment: It works OK now, all you are missing is to convert feature property `.NOME_COM` to upper case with `.toUpperCase()` method, since all your GeoJSON properties are upper case.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works perfectly now :)